# List EMPTY directories in Windows Azure Blob storage container

Tags: c#, directory, containers, azure-blob-storage

I want to list out all the directories, **including EMPTY**, of Azure Blob Storage Container. There are many ways to list the directories and I'm able to do it. Can anyone please tell me how to get empty directories too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as an empty directory on the blob service.

Directories on the blob service are virtual. When you create x/y/z we don't actually create a directory 'x' and a directory 'y' -- we create a blob with the name x/y/z. For conveniences sake we allow you to list with the delimiter '/' which returns x as though it were a directory. However, if you delete blob x/y/z and there were no other blobs with the prefix x/y, x and y would simply stop being listed as directories.

If you want a more directly parallel file system concept including support for empty directories, check out Azure Files.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. I am using Azure Explorer from Cerebrata and there is an option to create New Folder. It creates empty directory in selected container and list it. I created empty directory yesterday and when I open Azure Explorer and my storage container, that empty directory was not there. Finally you are right, we can not create empty directory. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you please provide some reference for Azure Files?

Comment: Getting started (I'm not sure what language you're on, but you should be able to find other languages as well): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/
Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx

Comment: Thanks :). I'm using C#